Why does the Rambam seem to include this as part of what is celebrated on Chanuka
The Rambam Hichos Chanuka 3:1 includes as a part of the of the Chanuka story וְהוֹשִׁיעָם מִיָּדָם וְהִצִּילָם וְגָבְרוּ בְּנֵי חַשְׁמוֹנַאי הַכֹּהֲנִים הַגְּדוֹלִים וַהֲרָגוּם וְהוֹשִׁיעוּ יִשְׂרָאֵל מִיָּדָם וְהֶעֱמִידוּ מֶלֶךְ מִן הַכֹּהֲנִים וְחָזְרָה מַלְכוּת לְיִשְׂרָאֵל יֶתֶר עַל מָאתַיִם שָׁנָה עַד הַחֻרְבָּן הַשֵּׁנִי:  (Hashem), delivered them from their hand, and saved them. The sons of the Hasmoneans, the High Priests, overcame [them], slew them, and saved the Jews from their hand. They appointed a king from the priests, and sovereignty returned to Israel for more than 200 years, until the destruction of the Second Temple.
He goes further in saying what the Neis Chanukaa was but the question is on the last sentence above. Firstly their appointing  a Kohen as a  king who was problematic.(see the Ramban Breshis 49:10)  Even if the Rambam disagrees with the Ramban about that, no one  disputes  that the  descendants of the Chasmanoim who became kings later on were not righteous people. Some of the more evil  future kings like Herod were not even  Jewish. Furthermore Herod  wasn't even the king. He needed Roman approval for his actions (see Bava Basra 4A) Apparently killing most of the Torah scholars wasn't something Herod felt he needed Roman approval. That should give a picture of what things were like during that time period. Even without further elaboration of how Chazal describe that time period.
Why does Rambam include  the subsequent period as a part of the Chanuka story? Why would secular or anti religious quasi Jewish sovereignty be something to celebrate ?  The non-Jewish King Agripas had a  lot better relationship with Chazal  than the most of Jewish sovereignty in those 200 years (see sotah 41 A & 41B)

I guess the Rambam was a Religious Zionist :P

Re: "non-Jewish King Agripas (sic) - You hold that "אחינו אתה" is sarcasm?

It was not sarcasm. The Gemora says it was chanufa. (forbidden flattery) Sotah 41B

Interestingly, the Satmar Rav (Chiddushei Torah, Chanukah, p. 102-103) also mentions this and says that if the Rambam saw the need to mention this, he was of the opinion that this part was also part of the miracle.
